# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column is of type bit but expression is of type character varying

Tags: database, postgresql, sql-insert, bit, liquibase

PostgreSQL database: one table has a field of data_type bit with a character_maximum_length of 1. When inserting data I get the error from the title. I am using liquibase to do the insert

```
<column name="shared" value="BIT(1)"/>
```

but tried a few other options (value="B'1'", valueBoolean="1" valueBoolean="true" ...), none of them working obviously

Comment: Have you tried type="BOOLEAN" value="true"? (The documenation speaks of the type="BOOLEAN" as a generic type to "make scripts database-independent", so it seems worth a try?)

Comment: works! thanks a lot. using valueBoolean="true" though